# Printing the contents of ScrollViewer in C# UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

My app is a universal windows 10 app and in a part of my app, I need to get some content printed.

Is there any way to simply print anything in an specific ScrollViewer including rectangles, Textblocks etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use [Content Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then binding the content to whatever you want (rectangles, textblocks ...)

Comment: Ok, I've done it. Now another question is that I want the content to be scaled to fit the page size. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @SaeedZeroOne I use `<ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"
                        Content="{Binding Content}" />`